# Timer event is not generated when C dll function is called

Tags: vb.net

```
    Net_mang_Form.Prg_bar.Visible = True
    Net_mang_Form.Prg_bar.Value = 0
    Net_mang_Form.prg_Timer.Start()

    Dim chk As Integer = file_send(dev_id, dev_type, Net_mang_Form.snd_file_path, ip_addr & "#1206", contrl_id)

    '=================== Upload Process is finished =====================

    Net_mang_Form.prg_Timer.Stop()
    Net_mang_Form.Prg_bar.Visible = False

    '====================================================================
```

Here `Net_mang_Form` is `Form1` and this code is written in button click event of `Form2`.

`file_send` is the function of dll .

`prg_Timer` is the timer control .

`Prg_bar` is Progress bar control.

Comment: You should provide some code to show us exactly what you're doing. And what Timer event are you talking about? Have you tried debugging through the code?

Comment: If it's a timer that's based on the `WM_TIMER` message you'll probably need to keep the message loop pumping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely subscribed to the Timer Elapsed event because I don't see that here in the code snippet?
[VB.NET Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet)

Answer (score 0):

If your timer is a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` then it will only be able to receive `WM_TIMER` notifications (which are converted into event callbacks into your code) with the UI thread you are running on is not busy.  If you are performing a blocking call that takes a long time, you will not get Timer events, button click events, or any other windows-message type events until the blocking call is completed.  You may want to consider the use of threading if you really need this behavior.